# iTextSharp 5.5.13.2 - Comb fields not showing spaces - NET Standard

Tags: itext

I've been using iTextSharp for a while without problems. I use it to fill out PDFs and I work with different types of fields. One of them are comb fields. Before version 5.5.13.2, comb fields would show spaces properly, like shown below:

[image: comb field working as expected]

However, when I migrated my project to net standard and installed iTextSharp 5.5.13.2 (`itextsharp.netstandard` in nuget), comb fields stopped working fine. When a PDF has multiple comb fields sharing the same name (this is required. I use the same name because I intend to have the same field in multiple places across the PDF file), only the first one has the right spacing, but the others do not:

[image: second instance of the comb field]

The curious thing is that when I click the comb field with no spaces in Adobe, the characters suddenly get spaced out fine, but when I stop clicking, then they get together again.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?